# Karate : passing value as query parameter from one response if that value is not null

Tags: karate

i have one response as below

"data":{"books":{"isbn":"97895113132","Bookid":10196333}}

sometimes i will get Bookid as null.

my question is, i have to take this bookid only if it is not null, and then pass to next api as query parameter.

please help to find the solution for this using karate framework

Answer (score 1):

Easy, if you use the [`params`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#params) keyword, any value of `null` is *not* sent as a param. You can try this:

```
* def temp = null

Given url 'http://httpbin.org'
And path 'get'
And params { foo: '#(temp)' }
When method get
Then status 200
```

If you are looking for conditional-logic - please read: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic